# What Java version does Protoc output? -- Protoc generated Java output does not compile

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to use the GTFS defined as a .proto file by Google here
https://developers.google.com/static/transit/gtfs-realtime/gtfs-realtime.proto

I download this file and compile it using protoc (`libprotoc 3.17.3`) which creates a `GftsRealtime.java` file. But when I try to compile this, I'm getting errors such as the following:

```
GtfsRealtime.java:2537: error: cannot find symbol
        UnusedPrivateParameter unused) {
        ^
...
GtfsRealtime.java:20170: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @java.lang.Override
    ^
```

Here is the `java --version` on my (MacOS) machine:

```
> java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

I feel like the the issue is that protoc is generating a different version of Java source code than I am running but I can't figure out what Java version is generated by `protoc`?

Comment: These errors have nothing to do with the Java version. Java 6, 7, or 8 _sources_ can be compiled with Java 9, for example. Ideally, you should upgrade to at least Java 11 as it is longer supported, but doesn't change that fact. If a class is not on the classpath, you get the first error. For the second, the `@Override` annotation is incorrectly placed

Comment: Well if Protoc were generating, say, Java 11 code, then my Java 9 would obviously not be forwards compatible. & for the error itself, you're not supposed to edit the Java output of Protoc -- hence why I am assuming there's a version mismatch.

Comment: That is true. I'd assume the issue is with the schema itself. If you have a class that says "Unused", then maybe there isn't going to be a class generated for it, for any Java version. But also, if it were creating code for Java 9+ and had `val` variable definitions, for example, you'd should expect to see errors specific to that

Comment: For the first error [adding this class to the classpath](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/3.17.x/java/core/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessageV3.java#L492) should fix that. For the override, I think you'll need to edit the file.

Comment: I'm confused by the suggestion to edit the generated output - the top of the file explicitly says `DO NOT EDIT!`

Comment: Okay. Then, can you show us what method is trying to be overridden? And if it is inherited from a parent class or interface? Then what class/interface is causing the issue?